# ViewModel return clear object when i try to get data from it

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to use `ViewModel`, for saving data to share between `Fragments`. That is it:

```
class AnimalViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var data = MutableLiveData<AnimalWithHints>()

    fun setData(animalData: AnimalWithHints) {
        data.value = animalData
        Timber.e("Saved?")
    }

    fun getData(): LiveData<AnimalWithHints> {
        if (data.value == null) {
            Timber.e("Null?")
            data.value = AnimalWithHints()
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

So I've filled **non-null object** *(checked it)* and I write before transaction:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AnimalViewModel::class.java).setData(animalWithHints)
```

I see *"Saved?"* when it happens, so I think save working good. I logged some field of `AnimalWithHints`, and I saw it was correct.

Then I try to get my object:

```
val animalWithHints = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AnimalViewModel::class.java).getData().value
```

And I see *"Null?"*. And it's true, `data.value` is rly new empty `AnimalWithHints` object.

Strange thing is I have only two lines of code, using `ViewModel`. I only save and get object, there is no place when I can clear it or modify somehow.

I need you help to understand what's wrong.

Comment: When you want to pass data between fragments that are on same activity, you'll need to create `ViewModel` instance by passing `getActivity()` as `Activity` context to it instead of **this** as `Fragment` context..

Comment: Yes, it works. Brilliant. You can form it to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to share data between your `Fragments` that are in same `Activity`, you'll need to create instance of `ViewModel` with context to `Activity`.

Below syntax provides you instance of `ViewModel` that is at `Fragment` level only *(You can share it at Fragment itself with some child fragments inside of that Frament)*:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this@Fragment)[SomeViewModel::class.java] // This will give you view model at fragment level
```

---

While passing `Activity` object to your `ViewModelProvider` inside your `Fragment` gives you `ViewModel` at `Activity` level. Hence You're having multiple Fragments inside same `Activity` meaning *context of Activity* is same gives your same `ViewModel` object at both `Fragments`.

So for sharing `ViewModel` between fragments, use below syntax :

```
ViewModelProviders.of(activity)[SomeViewModel::class.java] // This will provide you shared view model across multiple fragments.
```